# Postgres UTC to Java ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, postgresql-9.3

Follow-up question to my original [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417317/localdatetime-to-zoneddatetime).

Because I know that any date time used is against a known timezone, rather than where the user may be submitting their request from, I take a LocalDateTime, convert to UTC and persist.  Then, when the appointment is retrieved I convert the saved time to the meeting location timezone (stored in db).  However, it would seem that the values I save are actually being saved in my local timezone.

I receive a date time value in the Rest Controller such as:

```
startLocalDateTime: 2016-04-11T10:00
endLocalDateTime: 2016-04-11T10:30
```

Appointment has two ZoneDateTime fields:

```
@Column(name = "startDateTime", columnDefinition= "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
private ZonedDateTime startDateTime;
@Column(name = "endDateTime", columnDefinition= "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
private ZonedDateTime endDateTime;
```

Then I change the values to UTC and store on my entity to store to Postgres:

```
appointment.setStartDateTime(startLocalDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of( "UTC" )))
appointment.setEndDateTime(endLocalDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of( "UTC" )))
```

and I store that in Postgres `(columnDefinition= "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")`  When I look at the record in pgadminIII I see:

```
startDateTime "2016-04-11 04:00:00-06"
endDateTime  "2016-04-11 04:30:00-06"
```

So these appear to be stored properly in UTC format (please correct me if I am doing anything wrong so far).  I then retrieve them from the database and they are returned as:

```
Appointment
startdatetime: 2016-04-11T04:00-06:00[America/Denver]
enddatetime: 2016-04-11T04:30-06:00[America/Denver]
```

Those values are sent back as JSON:

```
{  
 "appointmentId":50,
 "startDateTime":"2016-04-11T04:00",
 "endDateTime":"2016-04-11T04:30"
}
```

So even though I am saving them as UTC, when I retrieve them they are in MST (my local) timezone, rather than UTC, and I am unable to convert them back to the actual time.

Still struggling with the persistence.  I have tried using the java.sql.timestamp, java.sql.Date, java.util.Date, and java.time.ZonedDateTime on my entity.  My Postgres is still a "timestamp with time zone".  But because I am using Spring-Data-JPA and need to query with the same type.  If I use Date - should that be sql.Date or util.Date?

Comment: They are still stored in UTC, because a Java Date **is** always in **UTC** (if it includes a local timezone then it has been formatted).

Comment: I guess I don't understand why the db shows them in UTC format and even when returned as part of an Appointment, the time is UTC but the zone appears to be "America/Denver" and not "UTC".  How can I get the correct time back?

Comment: How are you ***displaying*** the time? Because Java stores `Date` as a number of milliseconds since January 1 1970 at midnight UTC (aka EPOCH).

Comment: This is before display, when I retrieve from the database I see these values in the debugger, and then in the returned JSON (see updated question)

Comment: updated my question regarding your suggestion of Dates.

Answer (score 21):

You said:

> I take a LocalDateTime, convert to UTC and persist.

Nope. Stick with that `LocalDateTime` for booking appointments, no UTC involved for appointments.

When booking appointments that should appear as a certain time-of-day regardless of how politicians redefine the offset used within the time zone(s) under their jurisdiction, store a date with time-of-day but keep the time zone separate.

Politicians around the world have shown a strange penchant for frequently redefining the offset of their zones, adjusting to match or differ their neighbors, or to adopt or drop the foolishness known as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). These changes are done with little forewarning, or even none at all. So what is right now looks like 2:30 PM on a future day could become 1:30 PM, 2:00 PM, 3:30 PM, or who knows what the politicians might come up with, if we stored as a moment (date, time-of-day, zone/offset, all together).

### Java

To represent a date and time-of-day only, use [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). This class purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. This lack means this class does *not* track moments, is *not* a point on the timeline. So we generally do not use this class in business apps. Booking future appointments is one of the few cases where we *do* want this class.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;    // 2020-01-23. 
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 14 , 30 ) ;                      // 2:30 PM.
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( ld , lt ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/az011u).

> ldt.toString(): 2020-01-23T14:30

Store that in your database using JDBC 4.2 and later.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ldt ) ;
```

Retrieve from database.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class );
```

We need to track the intended time zone. Is this an appointment for a dentist office in Québec? Represent that fact as well. Keep in mind that a time zone is a history of past, present, and future (planned) changes to the offset-from-UTC used by the people of a particular region.

Use the `ZoneId` class to represent a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

Save that zone name as text to your database. Get its identifying name by calling [`ZoneId::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html#toString()). Do *not* use `ZoneId::getDisplayName` as that is for generating localized text for display to a user, but is not a formal identifier for the zone.

```
myPreparedStatement.setString( … , z.toString() ) ;
```

When your retrieve from database, reconstitute the `ZoneId`.

```
String zoneIdString = myResultSet.getString( … ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( zoneIdString ) ;
```

When you are generating a calendar for these appointments, if you need to determine (tentatively) points on the timeline, combine the date-with-time-of-day and the time zone together. Applying the `ZoneId` to the `LocalDateTime` produces a `ZonedDateTime`. This `ZonedDateTime` *is* a moment, *is* a point on the timeline, unlike `LocalDateTime`.

```
 ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/az011u).

> zdt.toString(): 2020-01-23T14:30-05:00[America/Montreal]

Of course, **we do *not* store that `ZonedDateTime`**. As discussed above this moment that right now appears to be 2:30 PM on the 23rd would turn into 1:30 PM or 3:30 PM if those busy politicians changed the time zone rules between now and then. We only use this `ZonedDateTime` tentatively, temporarily.

## Database

We store a `LocalDateTime` only in a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. You were incorrectly using `WITH` rather than `WITHOUT`, a major problem. For the `WITHOUT` type, Postgres stores the date and the time-of-day as given in the input. Even if a zone or offset were included with the input, Postgres would ignore the zone or offset.

Be aware that `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` is just the opposite in Postgres. The time zone or offset info accompanying an input is used to adjust the date and time to UTC. That UTC value is then stored. So values in a column of this type are **all in UTC**. Unfortunately, many tools have the anti-feature of dynamically applying a default time zone to the retrieved value before passing on to you. This creates the false illusion of a time zone being stored when in fact the value is in UTC. Retrieving as a `OffsetDateTime` will always tell you the truth. I say `OffsetDateTime` because, oddly, the JDBC 4.2 spec requires support for that class but not for the more commonly used `Instant` & `ZonedDateTime` classes. Your JDBC driver may support the other two classes, optionally. But all of this paragraph is neither here nor there, as we are *not* using `WITH` columns for future appointments.

As mentioned above, for future appointments should be stored in three (3) separate columns:

- `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` for the date and the time-of-day.
- `TEXT` (or similar type) for the identifying name of the intended time zone by which we want to view that appointment.
- `TEXT` (or similar) for the duration of the appointment, in standard ISO 8601 format. (see below)

## Points in your Question

You said:

> I receive a date time value in the Rest Controller such as:
>
> startLocalDateTime: 2016-04-11T10:00

So parse as a `LocalDateTime`. Such ISO 8601 compliant strings can be parsed directly by the *java.time* classes.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-04-11T10:00" ) ;
```

You said:

> endLocalDateTime: 2016-04-11T10:30

No. Do not store the ending time. The ending time you expect now could be different if time zone anomalies occur at that point. For example, what if your politicians adopt Daylight Saving Time (DST), then during the time of this appointment the "Spring ahead" 1-hour change of DST occurred? Then your half-hour meeting should run from 10:00 AM to 11:30 AM, while your recorded end-time would incorrectly read "10:30 AM" ending.

Generally the best way to handle appointments is to **record the duration of the appointment**, the span-of-time, rather than on the clock. As mentioned above, an appointment consists of three separate pieces of data: (1) starting date with time-of-day, (2) the intended time zone, and (3) duration of appointment. The ending should be dynamically calculated as needed, using [fresh current time zone data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/tz_database), for temporary use.

The [ISO 8601 standard includes a textual format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) for recording such durations: `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where `P` marks the beginning, and `T` separates any years-months-days from any hours-minutes-seconds. The *java.time* classes `Period` and `Duration` can parse such strings.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofHours( 1 ) ;
String output = d.toString() ;
```

See this code run live at IdeOne.com.

> output: PT1H

You can dynamically apply this duration to the `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ending = ldt.plus( d ) ;
```

Ditto for `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime ending = zdt.plus( d ) ;
```

You said:

> Appointment has two ZoneDateTime fields:

Nope. Make that a `LocalDateTime` field, not `ZonedDateTime`.

You said:

> @Column(name = "startDateTime", columnDefinition= "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")

Nope. Make that a column of type "TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE" to track a date and time-of-day without the context of zone/offset.

You said:

> Then I change the values to UTC and store on my entity to store to Postgres:

Nope. Booking appointments is one of the few cases where we do not want UTC. When tracking a moment, we generally do want to use UTC. But future appointments are not moments. We do not know the moment until we apply a time zone to the date-with-time-of-day, and we cannot do that ahead of time because we cannot trust politicians.

You said:

> Still struggling with the persistence.

Cannot help you there. I do not use either Spring or JPA, as they solve problems I do not have. I use straight JDBC.

You said:

> So these appear to be stored properly in UTC format (please correct me if I am doing anything wrong so far).

Nope, do not use UTC, do not store in UTC, not for appointments.

*Do* use UTC for moments though. For example, your logs should all be reporting each moment of an incident in UTC. Programmers & sysadmins would do well to learn to think in UTC while on the job. Keep a second clock on your desk set to UTC.

You said:

> when I retrieve them they are in MST (my local) timezone, rather than UTC, and I am unable to convert them back to the actual time.

We are not using UTC, nor any other time zone or offset-from-UTC in our appointment booking. So your problem vaporizes.

Tip: As I said above, your tools are likely lying to you about time zones. Set the tool and your session to UTC, if need be, to defeat this anti-feature.

You said:

> I have tried using the java.sql.timestamp, java.sql.Date, java.util.Date, and java.time.ZonedDateTime on my entity.

- Never use `java.sql.Timestamp`. Replaced by `OffsetDateTime` (and `Instant`).
- Never use `java.sql.Date`. Replaced by `LocalDate`.
- Never use `java.util.Date`. Replaced by `Instant`.

Use only the modern *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted those terrible date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. Those awful classes became legacy as of the adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL.]

Answer (score 1):

The jdbc driver has some knowledge about the timezone you are currently in. Generally I have gotten around this in the past by having the database do the timezone conversion for me, some derivative of "timestamp without time zone AT TIME ZONE zone" or "timestamp with time zone at time zone 'UTC'". It is in the guts of the postgres jdbc driver that it is figuring out what timezone the JVM is at and is using it in the save.

Comment: So you define your columns to be in timezone 'UTC' and then just use LocalDateTime or ZonedDateTime in the entities and business logic?  And then when you return your data, you convert from that UTC to the desired TimeZone?

Comment: Somewhat, I define my columns to be of type timestamp with time zone, then when I am persisting my times, instead of just doing a mycolumn = ?, I would do something like mycolumn = ? at time zone 'UTC', things get a bit tricky as it's easy to double account for the time difference. Another alternative if you are looking for a good across the board solution is to set this as the jdbc layer instead. Using a jvm parameter such as -Duser.timezone=UTC should do this for you across the board and it is easier, I am just unsure if all your tables need UTC or just this one.

Comment: So after some research it looks values are being saved as MST instead of UTC because of either my OS/JVM environment variable.   This is overriding my approach of converting to/from.  Since I am using Spring-Data-JPA w/Hibernate and not PreparedStatements, is there anyway to force it at this level, or should I use it when starting up my SpringBoot app?

Comment: I wouldn't know of any other way other than using sql or maybe hsql to convert the timestamp from the time zone which the JVM to whatever you need. I do think it will need to be done on the database level, not through any java construct, as the timezone is in the JVM. Alternatively if you can do it environment wide the -Duser.timezone=UTC in your web container JVM params will probably give you the same result.

Comment: I decided to use ZonedDateTime instead of Date for my entity.  This persists the values properly, but converting them back has proved problematic.  Please see my updated question....