# How to convert Datetime object into ZonedDateTime?

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have one object which is returning values in Datetime object. This attribute in mentioned in jar file so I am not able to join. When I got value I want to DateTime value into ZonedDateTime.

I searched on google but I didn't got any specific answers.

So any one can help me to solve this issue ?

Code : `DateTime datetime = reader.getValueAsDateTime();`

I want store into ZonedDateTime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LocalDateTime to ZonedDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417317/localdatetime-to-zoneddatetime)

Comment: Java doesn't have a `DateTime` class, so what is its fully-qualified name (and/or which library)?

Comment: eventually Joda-Time?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(datetime.getMillis()), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

where ZoneId.systemDefault() is system default timezone. You can change it as per your requirement.